# Javascript submit all forms one by one with one button click

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to submit multiple forms seperatly one by one with one button click. I populate my input forms with the SQL variable `$name` and `id="form<?= $i ?>"` depending on the result the creates the id form1,form2 etc. I then need to send all of these forms with one click. but seperetly from each other, so first the form with id form1 than form2 etc.

The problem. The way I have it now only submits one of the forms the last one that is generated. What am I doing wrong? The consol is not giving any errors and all the forms are generated with the correct Ids (form1,form2,form3 etc..)

PS: I cannot use ajax Xmlrequest for this matter.

```
$type = "test"
    $i=0;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM account WHERE purpose = ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$type);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result(); //only works when nd_mysli is set on the server!
    
        while ($rowid = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
         $name = $rowid['name'];
         
    $i++     
    
    
    ?>  <form method="post" id="form<?= $i ?>" target="_external" action="https://www.externalwebsite.com/index/post.php">    
        <input type="hidden" value="<?= $name ?>"  name="sendname" >
        </form>
    
       <?PHP } ?>
       <button id="submit">Submit</button>
       <script>
    
    document.getElementById( 'submit' ).addEventListener( 'click', function () {
        // check for and report errors here
        for( var index = 0; index < document.forms.length; index++ ) {
            document.forms[index].submit();
        };
    } );
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Why not just one `form` with multiple elements? You can use array notation on the names `name="sendname[]"` then iterate over it, or put `$id` inside it.

Comment: If you need to makes separate non-Xmlrequest submissions, then your hands are mostly tied by the inflexibility of the remote site.  I guess you'll need to force the user to limp through progressive single-forms.  Maybe retain their  progress via SESSION?

Comment: So if I understand correctly. It is not possible to submit the forms separately by using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem? Submitting a form (without using AJAX/fetch) is like clicking a hyperlink. It unloads the current page and moves to a new one. Therefore, the unsubmitted forms vanish.

You might be able to pull this off by creating hyperlinks with the fields you want sent to your server coded as url parameters, and with `target="blank"` in the anchor tags. Those will, of course, show up as GET operations at your server.

But your best bet is to figure out another way of solving this problem.

Comment: What other way should be possible? The forms and submit buttons can also be visible all together. I than have 10 of them. When I click them all 10 one by one there is no problem. So isnt there an solution that recreates that click or form submit?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't/can't use AJAX...
You could **load all your forms inside iframes**. When every single form submits the iframe might reload or do whatever the formAction tells to do, but your user main window will stay as-is.

```html
<iframe src="my-first-form.php"></iframe>
```

Otherwise the browser will follow the form `action` and refresh/navigate the page.